# Running into Attribute Errors while trying to configure PyWikiBot

Tags: python, module, attributes, wikipedia, pywikibot

I am currently following the [Python 3 Tutorial for Pywikibot](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Pywikibot_-_Python_3_Tutorial/Data_Harvest) and continue to experience attribute errors while running the included code from the tutorial as seen below.

```
import pywikibot

site = pywikibot.Site("en", "wikipedia")
page = pywikibot.Page(site, "Douglas Adams")
item = pywikibot.ItemPage.fromPage(page)

print(item)
```

While this is not the final step to achieve my goals, it has become a roadblock in my progression. From this code I should receive an output in the form of an `ItemPage-object` however I only receive the following error:

```
site = pywikibot.Site("en", "wikipedia")  # any site will work, this is just an example
AttributeError: module 'pywikibot' has no attribute 'Site'
```

I am quite new to programming and have only just scratched the surface, but I have taken some time to research attribute errors and how they may appear, as well as the fundamentals behind modules. At this point, however, I am pretty fried. Is it possible that my file/folder organization is causing this problem, or is there something more obvious that I am missing?

I am also wondering if I would be better off simply using a Wikipedia API to pull information and resources from Wikipedia/Wikidata for my project.

Thank you, please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Are you using python3 and have you installed pywikbot with pip3 ?

Comment: Yes, I am currently using Python 3.7 and have pip installed pywikibot. I've followed the tutorial up until that point.

Comment: It seems you have not installed Pywikibot properly or you are missing some important step. To find out more, please share more details and tracebacks it gives you.

Comment: It is weird, because you already successfully run the same lines in the previous tutorial pages. Perhaps also try to reinstall pywikibot